# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator and Identity Server, do they work and integrate together

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am thinking of integrating WSO2 Identity server with WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0.
so that user authentication can be done by WSO2 Identity server.
Please advise

Comment: Can you explain more about the user authentication you are referring to? Is it when logging in to the server? or authenticating the Proxy services & API?

Comment: Yes it is about authenticating the Proxy services & APIs

Comment: Or i will only use enterprise integrator authentication? i got confused because i am seeing that wso2 have the identity server so i thought of a way of integrating the two systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have secure proxies and APIs in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator itself.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Applying+Security+to+an+API
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service

On a further note, have you considered WSO2 API Manager as well? It combines features from both WSO2 Enterprise Integrator and WSO2 Identity Server. https://wso2.com/library/articles/2018/07/securing-apis-with-wso2-api-manager/

Based on the use case, the product you want to use might differ. If you want to do more integration (ie you want to connect to many different systems), WSO2 EI is more suitable. If you want to do API management, you can use WSO2 API manager. You can use both together as well. Do the integration in EI, and expose it securely via WSO2 API manager.

Comment: This information helped me a lot.
i will read about their integration.

Comment: Is the integration about publishing the EI wsdls to the API manager?